# Minecraft Specifiers : Scoreboard Objectives

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm quite used to Minecraft commanding, yet I do not know how to specify that a scoreboard objective called "POINTS" must have an integer higher than 749 so as to trigger the following command block:

```
/fill x y z x y z minecraft:air
```

I just need the first part sorry! I know that `r` stands for radius, but I can't find a list of other specifiers. A link to a list would be (probably) the most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of all target selector arguments can be found in the wiki here:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments

[image: Selector argument table]

To select players with `POINTS >= 750`, you should be using the `score_name_min` argument, and your selector should look something like `@a[score_POINTS_min=750]`.

Comment: Alright thanks ill be sure to keep the link in my desktop (:.